# Mudar valor de um vetor em uma função

Tags: c

Como faço?
Estou tentando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int changeMap(char mp[], int x, int y){
    mp[x-1][y-1] = 'X';
return 0;
}
int main(){
    char map[][1] = "gabriel";
    printf("%c", map[0][0]);
    changeMap(map, 1, 1);
    printf("%c", map[0][0]);
return 0;
}
```

O desejado é que retorne:

```
t
X
```

Mas retorna:

```
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c||In function 'changeMap':|
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c|4|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c||In function 'main':|
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c|8|error: invalid initializer|
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c|10|warning: passing argument 1 of 'changeMap' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
G:\PROJETOS\C\main.c|3|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[1]'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tens nesse código algumas coisas erradas:

- Tens de inicializar o mapa de carateres antes de o usar;
- Não podes atribuir uma string a um caractere;

  <strike>`char map[][1] = "gabriel";`</strike>

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int changeMap(char mp[N][N], int x, int y)
{
    mp[x-1][y-1] = 'X';
    return 0;
}
int main()
{        
    char map[N][N];  //inicialização do map de N por N
    map[0][0]= 'T';  //atribuição do 'T' a posição x=0, y=0

    printf("%c", map[0][0]);
    changeMap(map, 1, 1);
    printf("%c", map[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
TX
```

[Funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/MIrPt9)

Comment: Achei que para modificar diretamente map teria que criar um ponteiro para char, mas assim funcionou.

Comment: Também tem outra coisa, a sua função returna 0 que está jogado fora, é melhor ser `void` não ?

Comment: Isso depende @axell13... Eu apenas mantive o código do AP.

Comment: Entendi. Ótima resposta.